# Relay not updating after doing subsequent mutations

Tags: relayjs, graphql-js, relaymodern, graphql-relay

Currently, we stumbled across a problem doing mutation in relay modern. We have a diary which contains many entries. Whenever user add a entry which day of diary doesn't exist, we also create a diary before create a entry. Everything works as expected but the UI doesn't update immediately after the mutations. Here's the code.

AddDiaryMutation

```
import { commitMutation, graphql } from 'react-relay';

const mutation = graphql`
mutation AddDiaryMutation($input: AddDiaryInput!) {
  createDiary(input: $input) {
     diary {
        id
        ...EntryList_entries
     }
  }
}
`;

let clientMutationId = 0;

const commit = (environment, { date }, callback) =>
commitMutation(environment, {
    mutation,
    variables: {
      input: {
        date,
        clientMutationId: clientMutationId++
      }
    },
    onCompleted: response => {
    const id = response.createDiary.diary.id;
    callback(id);
  }
});

export default { commit };
```

AddEntryMutation will get the id from AddDiaryMutation response to add entry.

```
import { commitMutation, graphql } from 'react-relay';
import { ConnectionHandler } from 'relay-runtime';

const mutation = graphql`
mutation AddEntryMutation($input: AddEntryInput!) {
   createEntry(input: $input) {
     entryEdge {
       node {
         id
         project {
           name
         }
         speaker {
            name
         }
        } 
      }
     }
    }
   `;

function sharedUpdater(store, diaryId, newEdge) {
    const diaryProxy = store.get(diaryId);
    const conn = ConnectionHandler.getConnection(diaryProxy, 
       'EntryList_entries');
    ConnectionHandler.insertEdgeAfter(conn, newEdge);
} 

let clientMutationId = 0;

  const commit = (environment, { diaryId, ...rest }, callback) =>
     commitMutation(environment, {
       mutation,
       variables: {
         input: {
            ...rest,
            clientMutationId: clientMutationId++
         }
       },
       updater: store => {
          const payload = store.getRootField('createEntry');
          const newEdge = payload.getLinkedRecord('entryEdge');
          sharedUpdater(store, diaryId, newEdge);
       },
       onCompleted: () => callback()
});

export default { commit };
```

EntryList fragment

```
fragment EntryList_entries on Diary {
  entries(first: 20) @connection(key: "EntryList_entries", filters: []) 
{
    edges {
      node {
        ...Entry_entry
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Entry fragment

```
fragment Entry_entry on Entry {
  id
  project {
    name
  }
  speaker {
    name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with this updater also. I recommend console.log on every variable and see where the chain brakes. I have issues with my getConnection method (and i am changing my schema to include edges also). You can also console log the store from your environment to check the records there.